# Conditionally adding to an object literal in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, conditional-statements, literals

[image: sample code]

I would like to conditionally fill a property based on the target type.

I need to do this inside an event handler for a form (react).

I would like an if/else statements situations that encompasses what I am trying to do in line 41 and 42, but I don't know how.

How can I implement an if/else statement or a switch in object literals assigning?

As you can see from the image, I have tried nesting a ternary operator, while I am glad to see that it doesn't show any errors in my code, it still does not work.

I was trying to use basic if/else statements but wasn't succesful.

Comment: don't paste code as an image. What does it mean it doesn't work? It should work fine

Comment: You don't do it in the object literal. Do it on the object instead. Remove all the conditional stuff from your object literal. After that do `if (some_condition) {newFormData[e.target.name] = somevalue}` -- there, simple normal if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually pass the **value** directly to your handleChange function. That way you don't have to use a ternary operator. Take a look at this example:

```
const handleChange = (attribute, value) =>
  setInitialState((prev) => ({
    ...prev,
    [attribute]: value
  }));
```

And in your form use it like this:

```
return (
  <form>
    <input
      type="text"
      name="username"
      value={username}
      onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.name, e.target.value)}
    />
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      name="accept"
      checked={accept}
      onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.name, e.target.checked)}
    />
  </form>
);
```